# how to get the base url?

Tags: php

How can I get the exact base url? for example:

if the user type like this: https://stackoverflow.com/ I have to get the same also and if like this:  http://www.stackoverflow.com/. i have to get the same url also.

thanks in advance

Comment: do you want the part after the base url? also, google can answer this easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable has a lot of values you may want to consider, one of them being `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` (if you want the site that's being queried).

```
$thisSite = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

geting if they used a www, use [stripos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],'www.') === 0) { /* they used www */ }
```

Comment: How would I know if the user typed in the browser has www?

Comment: Hi Brad,
Thank you for your reply I really appreciate it but your code its not working because if the user typed: "http:// www.sample.com" and when i print the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] it will get only sample.com.

Comment: Well, them I'm out of ideas and not quite sure you can get that value. Most forums/web services offer a config file for you to supply the "root domain", which implies it's not easily retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

For URLs like:
`localhost/myblog/`
`http://domain.com/blog/`

use: [get_site_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_site_url)